# how to check if a method is internally called

Tags: node.js

How can I see if the `keepSocketAlive()` method was called internally

The below code is just for testing, what I would like to have a code or tool to see if a specific method is called internally or not

```
var http = require('http');

http.globalAgent.keepSocketAlive();      // this method is called internally when request is detached from the socket and the connection can be persisted
                                         // basically is the same as 'socket.unref()'
                                         // how can I see if that's really the case ?
```

Comment: Sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346503/what-is-the-opposite-of-the-xy-problem). Why do you need to know this?

Comment: It would give me deeper understanding of how Agents work (in this specific case)

Comment: Feel free to read the [source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/8a6fab02adab2de05f6e864847f96b0924be0840/lib/_http_agent.js).